# What does Bitcoin Core use port 8334 for?

Tags: bitcoin-core, port

Bitcoin Core listens on three ports, as can be seen by running the following command after it has started:

> `sudo netstat -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

By default, the ports it listens on are:

- 8332 for the RPC client (i.e. `bitcoin-cli`)
- 8333 for bitcoin clients (other nodes who want to contact this node)
- 8334 for ????

Searching for information on port 8334 does not seem to turn up anything useful.

By observation, if the port is already bound to, it does not cause a fatal error. Bitcoin Core continues to start, although the `debug.log` shows the following:

> `Unable to bind to 127.0.0.1:8334 on this computer. Bitcoin Core is probably already running.`

What does Bitcoin Core use port 8334 for?

Furthermore, other ports can be overridden using command-line arguments such as `-rpcport=18332` and `-port=18333` or similar configuration options in `bitcoin.conf`. How can Bitcoin Core be made to listen on a different port number than 8334 for whatever it uses that port for?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is used for incoming Tor connections.

See [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/6ef84e0503994c53f77093e7ea5951a7b0edea7a/doc/tor.md) and [here](https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/623745ca74cf3f54b474dac106f5802b7929503f/src/chainparamsbase.cpp#L40) for more info.

You can use `-bind=127.0.0.1:XXXX=onion` to use port `XXXX` instead.